# Canvas images repeating when filled instead of using new image

Tags: jquery, canvas

when I run this code back to back, normally it works. but for some reason it's not changing the canvas image the second time it's called.... it's using the same base canvas image and i don't know why.

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wj2f9mhv/1/

here is the code:

```
//default values
var currentFill = "#cccccc";
var oldcolor = '';
var oldxImgToBeFilled = '';
var imgSection ;
var canvas;
var ctx;
var imgToBeFilled = new Image();
var imgFill = new Image();  
var xImgToBeFilled = new Array();
var xBlank = new Array();


xImgToBeFilled[1] =  "http://testing.treesclothing.com/images/canvas/top_slim_wrap_white.png";
xImgToBeFilled[6]  = "http://testing.treesclothing.com/images/canvas/skirt_knee_wrap_white.png";

function fillColorOrPattern(imgSection,currentFill){
   console.log('fillCOlorOrPattern imgSection:' +imgSection);


    imgToBeFilled = new Image();

    imgToBeFilled.onload = function () {
        //if ((oldcolor !== currentFill) || (oldxImgToBeFilled !== xImgToBeFilled[extractNumber(imgSection)])){
            fill(imgSection,currentFill);
        //}
    };


        imgToBeFilled.src = xImgToBeFilled[extractNumber(imgSection)];

    console.log('fillColorOrPattern imageToBeFilled: '+xImgToBeFilled[extractNumber(imgSection)]);
}



// fillColorOrPattern() -- fillColor()|| fillPattern() -- fill()
// last step 
function fill(imgSection,currentFill){
    console.log('fill imgSection:' + imgSection);
    canvas = document.getElementById(imgSection);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    clear();

    ctx.drawImage(imgToBeFilled, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";   
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


     console.log(xImgToBeFilled[extractNumber(imgSection)]);


}

//gets the numerical step number from imgSection 
function extractNumber(varChar){
    return varChar.replace('s','').replace('image','');
}

//must clear canvas before adding any new color or pattern
function clear() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
}

//i also tried doing it this way
$.when(fillColorOrPattern('s1image',currentFill)).then(fillColorOrPattern('s6image',currentFill));
```

// the one thing that did work... but i can see how this can fail is to put a timeout around the second function:

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    fillColorOrPattern('s6image',currentFill);
  }, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `imgToBeFilled.onload` send the reference `this` to method fill. Like this

```
imgToBeFilled.onload = function () {
  fill(imgSection, currentFill, this); // <--- notice the 3rd parameter
};
```

In the fill method use that reference to drawImage. Something like this

```
function fill(imgSection, currentFill, img) {
    console.log('fill imgSection:' + imgSection);
    canvas = document.getElementById(imgSection);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    clear();

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ......
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/wj2f9mhv/2/**

Comment: this worked great, but now something is happening with the coloring of the images.... hard to tell from the abbreviated code i sent. i'm accepting this as the answer but hoping you would know why the images wouldn't color in appropriately now.

Comment: you mean a background color for the images?

Comment: yah.... its kind of the same problem where the functions are running at the same time- trying to color the two images- so one gets colored twice as dark and the other doesn't get colored.